# Capture Windows screen with ffmpeg

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, screen-capture

The [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) is cross-platform and very powerful software to handle video/audio or to stream it.
On Linux ffmpeg can capture X11 screen with a command below:

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -r 25 -s cif -i :0.0 out.mpeg
```

But is it possible to grab Windows Desktop with ffmpeg?

Comment: off topic for this site

Answer (score 90):

Use the [built-in GDI screengrabber](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#gdigrab) (no install needed) like this :

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -i desktop [output]
```

This will capture ALL your displays as one big contiguous display.

If you want to limit to a region, and show the area being grabbed:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate ntsc -offset_x 10 -offset_y 20 -video_size 640x480 \
-show_region 1 -i desktop [output]
```

To grab the contents of the window named "Calculator":

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=Calculator [output]
```

I found that framerate 10 suits screen capture well (you can change it).

I have encoded to both files and streaming outputs and it works quite well.

Comment: the experience with ffmpeg using gdigrab in windows 10 is rather awful.

Comment: @scape indeed. Is there anything that fixes that?

Comment: Works well in Windows 10 with ffmpeg-3.2.2 static.

Comment: is there any way we can capture crop desktop from where we like ?

Comment: this answer seems to be obsolete, -offset_x is no option

Comment: How do you make the recording stop?

Comment: @Royi: Ctrl + c

Comment: @Bowi, Is that the official way? Isn't there more elegant way?

Comment: Wow, never thought about that. :-D **I think** that Ctrl+C does not *kill* the program but just *interrupts* it. Ffmpeg prints some more lines after the key press, so it cannot have been *killed*, and it also says "Exiting normally, received signal 2.", so I think it is the official way of ending the recording.

Comment: @Royi You can also hit 'Q' to quit ffmpeg.

Comment: if several monitors are connected, how can I record the required one?

Answer (score 16):

This will help for capturing the working screen on windows :

> ffmpeg -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:00:30 -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p c:/video_comapre2.mp4

Comment: How to grab audio too ?

Comment: what is the purpose of the -`t 00:00:30` parameter

Comment: @DankCoder it's sys , to what duration the code will keep running and recording

Answer (score 8):

*this code is tried successfully on windows XP Sp3 and ffmpeg (last version 28/12/2012 for windows)
-ffmpeg.exe must be copied in c:\windows\system32 directory for being accessed from anywhere from your PC)
ScreenCapture can be downloaded for free (google). Install it (msi file). Its registered automatically from the (ScreenCapture.ax file). It's sent with an IscrenCapture.h file also.

-capture screen video and audio (adjust the device audio you have-mine is RealTek AC97
 Audio)
I cannot install params of UscreenCapture in registry (tried even on IscrenCapture.h file ).It always provide the full scren capture only.
There is an error in registry location,in parameters types (dwords are specified by the author but reg_binary is installed)...
then i used the crop() ffmpeg function to capture any region on the screen.the command line is :

`xwidth`, `xheight` are the width & height of the region want to capture.
`xleft`, `xtop` the coord of the top left point of the rectangle capture.

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Realtek AC97 Audio" -vf crop=xwidth:xheight:xleft:xtop c:\output.flv
```

to capture video only can use

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -vf  crop=xwidth:xheight:xleft:xtop c:\output.flv
```

NB: x11grab dont work on windows (it's specifically for Linux/X11)
   can use wscript.shell to code the line command silently.
    i used the format video output as flv because i have the best rendering and small capacity.I dont success with mp4.

you can know your media devices with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

-you can record any sound from your pc with this command line (adapt the device you have):

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Realtek AC97 Audio" -acodec libmp3lame "c:\out.mp3"
```

Answer (score 5):

ffmpeg windows static version 4.2.2, screen recording with audio

to check your microphone

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

next copy your audio="YOUR MICROPHONE OR STEREO MIX", mine is "Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)".

```
ffmpeg -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (Realtek High Definition Audio)" -f -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:00:30 -framerate 30 -probesize 10M -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p "d:\ffmpeg_testing.mp4"
```

Answer (score 3):

A patch to implement this was sent to the [ffmpeg mailing list](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2011-January/107042.html) a while back. This would have implemented `gdigrab` to work just like `x11grab`.

Also, the [ffmpeg codec page](http://ffmpeg.org/general.html) says "VfW" (Video for Windows? aka DirectShow?) capture is supported.

Comment: this has (I think) been committed now.

Answer (score 2):

http://nerdlogger.com/2011/11/03/stream-your-windows-desktop-using-ffmpeg/

explains how to do it.

basically, install uscreencapture dshow filter, then
ffmpeg -f dshow  -i video="UScreenCapture" out.mp4

Comment: I get error: `[dshow @ 01065fc0] Could not find video device.
video=UScreenCapture: Input/output error
Conversion failed!`

Answer (score 1):

This can be done without using `x11grab/xcbgrab/gdigrab` with help of the below commands in `linux` .

To record a video,

```
 ffmpeg -f x11grab  -s 1366x768 -i :0.0 -r 25 -vcodec libx264  output.mkv
```

To record a frame,

```
./ffmpeg -f fbdev -framerate 1 -i /dev/fb1 -frames:v 1 screenshot3.jpeg
```

Answer (score -1):

I would like to add the command I use to capture the screen:

```
ffmpeg.exe -y ^
-vsync vfr ^
-f gdigrab ^
-indexmem 300M ^
-rtbufsize 1G ^
-probesize 7M ^
-max_probe_packets 50k ^
-draw_mouse 0 ^
-video_size 1280x720 ^
-offset_y 152 ^
-framerate 24 ^
-c:v bmp ^
-strict strict ^
-thread_queue_size 50k ^
-r 24 ^
-i desktop ^
-f dshow ^
-channel_layout stereo ^
-thread_queue_size 50k ^
-strict strict ^
-i "audio=Stereo-mix (Realtek High Definition Audio)" ^
-map 0:v ^
-max_muxing_queue_size 50k ^
-f mp4 ^
-movflags +faststart ^
-max_interleave_delta 0 ^
-c:v libx264 ^
-r 24 ^
-preset fast ^
-tune film ^
-strict strict ^
-crf 25 ^
-pix_fmt yuv422p ^
-map 1:a ^
-max_muxing_queue_size 50k ^
-max_interleave_delta 0 ^
-c:a aac ^
-strict strict ^
-ac 2 ^
screencapture.mp4
```

The value of probesize appears to have much influence on the audio/video synchronisation. Raising the value by a few megabytes may cause A/V out of sync. Change by 1M or 500k, e.g. to 7500k, at a time.
If you leave out the probesize option, ffmpeg will, by default, set the probesize to 5M.

max_interleave_delta option prevents ffmpeg forcing output. If ffmpeg forces output, a message will appear in your log, e.g.:
[mp4 @ 00000199f7512040] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10007271 > 10000000: forcing output

If ffmpeg takes to much processor time, try changing the -preset option (ultrafast, superfast, veryfast, faster, fast, medium (default), slow, slower, veryslow), larger -crf (constant rate factor), e.g. 32 or lower framerate (-framerate and -r options on several places in the command).