# Pushing Live Smooth Streaming multi track audio to Azure Media Services with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, audio-streaming, azure-media-services

Does anyone has a working command line for FFMPEG that shows how to stream audio from multiple devices (sound cards) using Smooth Ingest and a Basic Pass-through channel type (the cheapest option on Azure Media Services)?

The command should allow me to show multiple audio tracks (with language identifiers) using the Azure Media Player demo site (http://ampdemo.azureedge.net).

Appreciate any help.

I have tried many many examples with no success...

Comment: Please post your question in MS Q&A Forum of [Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/25375/azure-media-services.html) for the document-based suggestions/answers.

Comment: This is a question for ffmpeg usage. The target is Azure although the question is about ffmpeg usage. 
Don’t understand why this was closed.

Comment: Refer to the article of [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HariKrishna - I edited the question to make sense and I can answer it if you reopen it.  I answered it in the MS Q&A forum already as well.

Comment: @JeanP - I also created this new sample page in our Javascript samples for reference.
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Live/FFmpeg/ffmpeg_commands.md

Comment: Sure @johndeu, Reopened!

Comment: thanks @HariKrishna - Added my answer here as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have this example FFMPEG ingest for Smooth that you can try to play with. First, if you are working on Windows, you will want to list all of your DirectShow devices to get the inputs that are available. Otherwise, follow the usual ffmpeg directions for devices on other OS's.

```
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
```

Then you can play around with this sample command line and see if you can match up your audio inputs.

Video and Audio with GoPro need to set rtbufsize to large value and I had to play around with the audio offset delay (-itsoffset) to get av sync correct.

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -i audio="Headset Microphone (Logitech Stereo H650e)" -itsoffset 1.00 -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -rtbufsize 2000M -i video="GoPro Webcam" -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 192k -c:v:1 libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s:v:0 1280x720 -r 30-g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -minrate:v:0 3000k -maxrate:v:0 3000k -b:v:0 3000k -f ismv -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -frag_duration 1600000 "http://<YOURCHANNEL>-nimbuspm-uswe.channel.media.azure.net/<CHANNEL_ID>/ingest.isml/Streams(video)"
```

I got this to work nicely with my laptop microphone, and my USB Logitec headset audio. I set one track to "english" and the other to "spanish" so it shows up in the dropdown list in the Azure Media Player demo site (ampdemo.azureedge.net). I still had to mess around with the AVSync setting (-itsoffset) a bit to make it look right.

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -rtbufsize 15M -i audio="Microphone Array (Synaptics Audio)" -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -i audio="Headset Microphone (Logitech Stereo H650e)" -itsoffset 1.00 -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -rtbufsize 2000M -i video="GoPro Webcam" -map 0:a:0 -map 1:a:0 -map 2:v:0 -metadata:s:a:0 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 language=spa -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 192k -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 192k -c:v:2 libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s:v:0 1280x720 -r 30 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -minrate:v:0 3000k -maxrate:v:0 3000k -b:v:0 3000k -f ismv -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -frag_duration 1600000 "http://<YOURCHANNEL>-nimbuspm-uswe.channel.media.azure.net/<CHANNEL_ID>/ingest.isml/Streams(video)"
```

To do screen recording, depending on what OS you are on, there are many ways to do that - [Capture Windows screen with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6766333/capture-windows-screen-with-ffmpeg)

```
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f dshow -fflags nobuffer -i audio="Headset Microphone (Logitech Stereo H650e)" -itsoffset 1.00 -f gdigrab -framerate 10 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -video_size 1920x1080 -show_region 1 -i desktop -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 192k -c:v:1 libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -s:v:0 1280x720 -r 30 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -sc_threshold 0 -minrate:v:0 3000k -maxrate:v:0 3000k -b:v:0 3000k -f ismv -movflags isml+frag_keyframe -frag_duration 1600000 "http://<YOURCHANNEL>-nimbuspm-uswe.channel.media.azure.net/<CHANNEL_ID>/ingest.isml/Streams(video)"
```

I created a new page of example command lines in our Javascript/Node.js SDK sample repo up here:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Live/FFmpeg/ffmpeg_commands.md

I gathered up as many samples as I could locate right now. Feel free to add or suggest more if you come up with any good ones.